# Halogen lights charing floor beams

Tags: light-fixture, safety

I was replacing a halogen spot light bulb earlier on and I spotted fair amount of charing on one of the upstairs floor beams which was very close to the light fixture. Damage can be seen in the picture. Upon further inspection I found 4 other light fixtures caused similar damages to the beams and insulation around them. 
How can I make the fixtures safe? Changing halogen lights to led would reduce to amount of heat they produce but would that be enough? Moving them all could be a hard job since some of them is in awkward spots under tiled floors etc. [image: damage on the beams]

These are the current type of bulb and fixtures
[image]
[image]

Comment: I knew halogen bulbs got hot, but I didn't realize they got *that* hot!

Comment: I recently switched some halogen flood lights to LED different lamp style they run much cooler than the halogen and the light quality and lumens are hard to tell apart now to see if they last.

Comment: @JAB perhaps you missed the epidemic of house fires from those "500W halogen torchieres" that were all the rage then.  Yes, they can exceed 600F.  They also get used as the fuser heat source in laser printers.  They are basically heat generators which make a small amount of light also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can buy LED versions of these. Just put "gu10 led" in your favorite search engine. Typically, they'll use 3 to 7 watts. No way this will char anything.

But they are a bit expensive (on the flip-side they never burn).

Comment: Gu10 led's 5 watts €2.50 each. I changed the whole house 38 lights in total so I can sleep without a worry.